# Trying to get touch point, returns NaN

Tags: iphone, objective-c, location, touch, uigesturerecognizer

Okay, I'm running into a very strange (for me) problem here. I have a 150x150 button in my view and I've added a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to that button, because I need to get the point where the button has been pressed when it is pressed down. My code to do that looks like this:

```
-(CGPoint)detectedTouch:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender { 

    CGPoint touchPoint = [sender locationInView:button];
    return touchPoint;
}


-(void)myAction {

    CGPoint touchPoint = [self detectedTouch:myGestureRecognizer];  
    NSLog(@"touchPoint = %f, %f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);

    //do stuff
}
```

Now everything works just fine when the button is on a normal view. But when the button is on a scrollView, it only works when you press it down for about a second. If you release it too quickly, the log gives me this:

```
touchPoint = nan, nan
```

Any help to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIGestureRecognizer` have various states in their life span, such as possible, recognized, failed, ended, canceled. I would try putting a switch statement inside your recognizer method on the state and see which is happening to better narrow down the problem. It would look something like this:

```
switch (sender.state){
    case  UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:
        NSLog(@"possible");
        break;
    case  UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
        NSLog(@"Failed!");
        break;
    ... All Cases wanted
    default:
        break;
}
```

I don't know the internal details but perhaps if it fails/cancels it doesn't pick up the location in the view.

Here is the docs on subclassing gesture recognizers and the states that can happen.

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Okay, thanks for this, but somehow my problem is related to the scrollView. The point of getting the touch point was animating the button in a different way, depending on where you touch it. Just to test, I removed the part where I check for the touch location and made the button move down the y-axis when it is pressed down and move it back to its original position once it's no longer pressed. On a regular view it works as expected, but on a scrollView it only works after a delay (as described above) and the animation isn't fluid. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem, but was not successful. At first, I thought the gesture recognizer might be interfering with the scrollView scroll gesture recognizer, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Here is the code I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongHold:)];
//    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 2000)];
    lbl.text = @"lorem ipsum......";
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(lbl.frame.size.width, lbl.frame.size.height);
    [scrollView addSubview:lbl];
    btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150);
    [btn addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [scrollView addSubview:btn];

    v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    v.hidden = YES;
    [scrollView addSubview:v];
}

- (void) handleLongHold:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*) recognizer {
    NSLog(@"long tap handled");
    v.hidden = NO;
    v.center = [recognizer locationInView:btn];
}
```

By the way, I stumbled on your question looking for a way to find a touch point from a gesture recognizer selector - the locationInView method helped me, and hopefully this code helps you.